# Csvkit : use "in2csv" in python code

Tags: python, csv, csvkit

I'd like to use `in2csv` to convert excel files into csv in my python code, but without running it as a separate process using exec. Instead, I'd like to directly import the function and use it, like `in2csv("input.xls", "output.csv")`, or still better, get directly the structure of the file in python without using the csv reader out the output file.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue. I looked into the source code of `in2csv` and found it internally uses `agate` and `agateexcel`. I directly used agate and implemented the following way

For xls file

```
import agate
import agateexcel

table = agate.Table.from_xls('input.xls', sheet='sheet')

table.to_csv('output.csv')
```

For xlsx file

```
import agate
import agateexcel

table = agate.Table.from_xlsx('input.xlsx', sheet='sheet')

table.to_csv('output.csv')
```

https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/blob/master/csvkit/utilities/in2csv.py

Comment: How to specify delimiter?

Comment: In csv file while saving ?

Comment: yes.  sep and delimiter keyword are not accepted.